# Issue with vertical Alignment on multipul Bootstrap Tables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I know this is a real newbie question, but I am creating a simple responsive website for the inlaws :) (trying to get brownie points) and I am having issues with vertically aligning the text on multiple tables, so that all copy on all the tables align.

as you can see from the code below, i have multiple tables for each of the menu headers and currently the text is all over the place.

Any help you can give would be great :)

```css
/* -- custom css for Bootstrap 3.x --*/

/* move special fonts to HTML head for better performance */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Voltaire);

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
}

/* fix bs3 horizontal scrollbar bug */
.row { margin: 0; padding: 0 }


/* use special fonts in certain elements */
h1,h2,h3,h4,.lead,.btn,.navbar a {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family:'Voltaire',Arial,sans-serif;
  letter-spacing:2px;
}

h1 {
  font-size:50px;
}

/* make images gray */
img.grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}

.icon-bar {
   background-color:#fff;
}

.scroll-down a, .scroll-top a {
   color:#ffffff;
}

.scroll-down {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:20%;
   right:0%;
   color:#f9f9f9;
}

.scroll-top {
  background-color:#dbdbdb;
}

.vert {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:4%;
  text-align:center;
}

.header .btn-lg {
   font-size:28px;
   border-color:#eeeeee;
   padding:15px;
   background-color:transparent;
   color:#ffffff;
}

.header .btn-lg:hover {
   background-color:#eeeeee;
   color:#777777;
}

.navbar a {
  color:#fff;
  font-size:14px;
}

.navbar-bold.affix {
  background-color:#d46054;
}

.navbar-bold {
  background-color:#f58076;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.navbar-bold li a:hover, .navbar-bold li.active {
  background-color:#d46054;
}

    
.header h1 {
  font-size:80px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px rgba(f,f,f,0.1);
  color:#431a6d;
  color:#fff;
  margin-left:-5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.header .lead {
  color:#d46054;
  font-size:25px;
}

.header {
  height: 80%;
  background: #000000 url('file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/Azza/Downloads/JU51oUMIye/images/food.jpg') center center fixed;
}

/* use alt in navbar and header for different color */

.alt {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.alt .lead {
  color: #000000;
}

.alt.affix {
  background-color:#4C06AB;
}

.alt li a:hover, .alt li.active {
  background-color:#5D17BA;
}



.blurb {
  padding: 120px 0;
  background-color:#fefefe;
}

.blurb .panel {
  background-color:transparent;
}

.bright {
  background: #dbdbdb url('images/food.jpg') repeat center center fixed; 
  color:#777;
}

.featurette {
  background: #222334;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.featurette-item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.featurette-item > i {
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 56px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 136px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center;
}

.featurette-item > i:hover {
  font-size: 68px;
}

.callout {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top:7%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://www.bootply.com/assets/example/bg_suburb.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.gallery {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.call-to-action {
  background: #eeeeee;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.call-to-action .btn {
  margin: 10px;
}

footer {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

/* -- end custom css for Bootstrap 3.x --*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h1>Menu</h1><br>
        
        <h2>Starters</h2>
        
        <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Allergies</th>
      <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>1.</td>
           <td>Prawn Cocktail</td>
           <td>Fish</td>
           <td>£2.60</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>4.</td>
           <td>Chicken and Sweetcorn Soup</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£2.10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>5.</td>
           <td>Chicken and White Mushroom Soup</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£2.10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>6.</td>
           <td>Sesame Prawn on Toast</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7.</td>
           <td>Yuk Sung</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£6.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7a.</td>
           <td>Hot and Sour Soup</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£2.60</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7c.</td>
           <td>1/4 Aromatic Duck</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£8.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7c.</td>
           <td>1/2 Aromatic Duck</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£15.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7c.</td>
           <td>Whole Aromatic Duck</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£24.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7d.</td>
           <td>Chicken Wings with Peking Sauce</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7e.</td>
           <td>Chicken Wings with Satay Sauce</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7f.</td>
           <td>Chilli and Salted Chicken Wings</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7g.</td>
           <td>Chicken Skewer with Satay Sauce</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£5.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7h.</td>
           <td>Chicken Skewer with Peking Sauce</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£5.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7k.</td>
           <td>Mixed Starters</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£7.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7m.</td>
           <td>Deep Fried Wun Ton</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>7n.</td>
           <td>Crispy Seaweed</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.00</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
  
  <h2>Chinese Dishes</h2>
        
        <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Allergies</th>
      <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr>
     <td>8.</td>
           <td>BOWAN Special Rice</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£5.10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>9.</td>
           <td>BOWAN Special Chow Mein</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£5.10</td>
    </tr>
         </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
    <h2>Chop Suey Dishes (Beansprouts - Rice Extra)</h2>
        
        <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Allergies</th>
      <th>Price</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr>
     <td>10.</td>
           <td>Special Chop Suey</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.60</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>11.</td>
           <td>King Prawn Chop Suey</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>12.</td>
           <td>Shrimps Chop Suey</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.60</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>13.</td>
           <td>Chicken Chop Suey</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>15.</td>
           <td>Beef Chop Suey</td>
           <td></td>
           <td>£4.30</td>
    </tr>
         </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
    <h2>Sweet & Sour Dishes (Rice Extra)</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe start here depending on what you're really looking to do: you can set the width of the columns by adding col-**-* to your `th` also.

```css
* -- custom css for Bootstrap 3.x --*/
/* move special fonts to HTML head for better performance */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Voltaire);
 html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
/* use special fonts in certain elements */

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
.lead,
.btn,
.navbar a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Voltaire', Arial, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
}
/*New Rules*/

h1.table-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}
h2.menu-label {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h1 class="table-title">Menu</h1>

      <br>
      <h2 class="menu-label">Starters</h2>

      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Number</th>
            <th class="col-sm-4">Description</th>
            <th class="col-sm-4">Allergies</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1.</td>
            <td>Prawn Cocktail</td>
            <td>Fish</td>
            <td>£2.60</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4.</td>
            <td>Chicken and Sweetcorn Soup</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£2.10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5.</td>
            <td>Chicken and White Mushroom Soup</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£2.10</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6.</td>
            <td>Sesame Prawn on Toast</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£4.20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7.</td>
            <td>Yuk Sung</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£6.50</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7a.</td>
            <td>Hot and Sour Soup</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£2.60</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7c.</td>
            <td>1/4 Aromatic Duck</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£8.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7c.</td>
            <td>1/2 Aromatic Duck</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£15.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7c.</td>
            <td>Whole Aromatic Duck</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£24.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7d.</td>
            <td>Chicken Wings with Peking Sauce</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£4.20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7e.</td>
            <td>Chicken Wings with Satay Sauce</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£4.20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7f.</td>
            <td>Chilli and Salted Chicken Wings</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£4.20</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7g.</td>
            <td>Chicken Skewer with Satay Sauce</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£5.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7h.</td>
            <td>Chicken Skewer with Peking Sauce</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£5.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7k.</td>
            <td>Mixed Starters</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£7.50</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7m.</td>
            <td>Deep Fried Wun Ton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£4.00</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7n.</td>
            <td>Crispy Seaweed</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>£4.00</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <h2 class="menu-label">Chinese Dishes</h2>

      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Number</th>
            <th class="col-sm-4">Description</th>
            <th class="col-sm-4">Allergies</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <tr>
              <td>8.</td>
              <td>BOWAN Special Rice</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>£5.10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>9.</td>
              <td>BOWAN Special Chow Mein</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>£5.10</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <h2 class="menu-label">Chop Suey Dishes (Beansprouts - Rice Extra)</h2>

      <table class="table table-responsive table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Number</th>
            <th class="col-sm-4">Description</th>
            <th class="col-sm-4">Allergies</th>
            <th class="col-sm-2">Price</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <tr>
              <td>10.</td>
              <td>Special Chop Suey</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>£4.60</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>11.</td>
              <td>King Prawn Chop Suey</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>£4.90</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>12.</td>
              <td>Shrimps Chop Suey</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>£4.60</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>13.</td>
              <td>Chicken Chop Suey</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>£4.30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>15.</td>
              <td>Beef Chop Suey</td>
              <td></td>
              <td>£4.30</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for this, it has partly resolved the issue.

The tables headers are now aligned but when i reduce the size of the browser to match a mobile device, the last 2 columns on the tables disappear to the right. Is there away to keep the tables responsive?

Comment: What else are you having issues with?

Comment: stated above :) thanks for your help on this, i think i just need the text to wrap the text or something

Comment: Are you using the structure from the example I posted and are you talking about a screen size below 320px?

Comment: ah yes i missed some of the above code :) you are a super star, it looks perfect now. thanks again

Comment: No problem! And glad i could help!